# Website Anonymous Authentication is enabled even when set not to be

Tags: iis-7, wix, iis-7.5, wix3.5

During installation I create a web site under Default Web Site. For my web site, I set Anonymous Authentication to be disabled:

```
<iis:WebDirProperties Id="PSDirProperties" AnonymousAccess="no" BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
```

For most it works, but in some cases the Anonymous Authentication is set to Enabled.

Does anyone have an idea why is that or how to suppress that behavior?

Comment: Does the behavior depend on the same setting on a parent level? I've seen a similar behavior, but that time a setting by default was influenced by the parent setting...

Comment: I suspected that this is the issue, but also expected for wix forcing what is defined - which in most cases happens.